# Timthumb Could not find the internal image you specified

Tags: wordpress-theming

I am using Timthumb to reisze pictures in my wordpress blog.
It's woirking fine on my local machine but when upload it on remote server Timthumb return me the following error:

Could not find the internal image you specified.

And a 400 Bad request in browser console.

How to fix this? i've been told that it might depend from server path configuration.
Timthumb version i am using is:  2.8.10

Answer (score 2):

I just had that error and it was because it was looking for the file in the wrong place in the filesystem. **Enable debugging** and set it to level 3. Open the page where it says this error. Download the error log (same directory as the script). You'll see all the paths it tries. Output `dirname(__FILE__)` from just about anywhere. You'll see the real path it needs. Add it to the `timthumb-config.php` as

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = '/home/username/public_html';
```

Just as an example I had to do this (wrap in php tag). Previously it was using something with `/bin/usr/htdocs` in it, and that's too much detail!

Around line 850 in the `getLocalImagePath` funcion, add this:

```
$src = str_replace ( "~username/" , "" , $src );
```

This is optional, replace `username` with something else.

Another case where you are using some htaccess magic so the images are accessed like `/files/2012/02` rather than `/wp-content/uploads/2012/02` TimThumb would work well if it'd treat this as an external URL... But it treats it as internal and it won't find the images so set a docroot accordingly and you might need to use the replace hack mentioned previously.

Answer (score 0):

I have some tweaks on .htaccess to hide the fact that I'm using Wordpress.
On timthumb 2.8.11.

**After**

```
$this->localImage = $this->getLocalImagePath($this->src);
```

i'v **hadded** this line of code

```
$this->src = str_replace('/file/', '/wp-content/uploads/', $this->src);
```

The **/file/** in the normal WPway should be **/wp-content/uploads/**.